# mysql MULTI DELETE error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have mysql query

```
DELETE data 
    FROM table 
        WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
            AND status <> 0;
```

And i get this error:

> ERROR 1109 (42S02) at line 2: Unknown table 'date' in MULTI DELETE

How fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not defined.  You can use an alias or remove it altogether:

```
DELETE t 
    FROM table t
    WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND status <> 0;
```

Or just try:

```
DELETE FROM data
    WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND status <> 0;
```

Comment: >FROM table - 'table' its mysql table, not table name

Comment: @insciq . . . There is no `table` keyword in the `delete` syntax.